# HighCharts - number format with $ in its short form

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm using dotnet.highcharts to generate a chart.

If I do not set any label formatting on the y-axis labels, this is what is displayed.

[image]

This is good. 
So 200M = 200,000,000
And it looks like this is done automatically.

If I wanted to put a $ in front of the value and I use:

```
function() { return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0) ; }
```

Then the label will now display $200,000,000.

How would i get the format to display it with the short form with the dollar sign like $200M ?
thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case, you have to either take the pre formatted label, or rebuild the level of abbreviation you want in the formatter yourself.

In this case, you could something like

```
 yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '$'+this.value / 1000000 + 'M';
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't need to do that. Oh well.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128177/1411004), you can call the original formatter with:

```
this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Although it should be called in a formatter function.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code before call the chart

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```